# Accessing filter value list names inside ArcGIS Pro script tool using script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, trace, utility-network

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I want to access the the name parameter defined under the condition barrier parameter using the Python script to add some custom values.

How can I access the value list table defined inside the condition barrier?

[image]

Comment: Your description is vague, please provide an example. I think what you're after is an update cursor https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm is this question about ArcGIS for Desktop (as per the tag) or ArcGIS Pro (as per the title)?

Comment: I have updated the question , please let me know if it's understandable

Comment: Are you wanting to use ArcPy with the ArcGIS Pro application or the ArcMap application which are both part of the ArcGIS Desktop product?

Comment: Arcpy with arcgis pro

Answer (score 2):

Your screen shot is from the [Trace (Utility Network)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/utility-networks/trace.htm).
The Conditional Barriers are a Value Table.

You could add a value table and pass it to the trace with code something like this:

```
# Create the value table for the conditional_barriers with 5 columns
conditional_barriers = arcpy.ValueTable(5)
# [Name, Operator, Type, Value, Combine Using]
filter_barriers.addRow([attribute_name, 'IS_EQUAL_TO', 'SPECIFIC_VALUE', some_value, 'AND'])
# filter_barriers.addRow(more traversability barrier condition)

# Trace
arcpy.un.Trace(in_utility_network, trace_type, conditional_barriers=conditional_barriers)
```

Comment: actually i want to create the condition barrier parameters value table same as created in un.trace tool but i am not able to create that , can you please help me in that.